# A new way to generate Triangular Numbers...interesting?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, numerical-linear-algebra

An open ended question...

In my work in aerodynamics, lifting line theory specifically, there is a matrix $Q$ that relates vortex strength to wing downwash. While fiddling with the problem and recoding it for Mathematica, I stumbled onto the result that the sum of the elements of $Q^{-1}$, if it is an $n$-dim square matrix, is just the Triangular number $T(n) = (n+1)n/2$.

It kind of startled me, as when just eyeballing the inverse matrix, nothing suggested it would have this property. $Q$ has elements
$$
q_{i,j}=\frac{1}{1-4 (i-j)^2}
$$

Here's a 4D example of $Q$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{15} & -\frac{1}{35} \\
 -\frac{1}{3} & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{15} \\
 -\frac{1}{15} & -\frac{1}{3} & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 -\frac{1}{35} & -\frac{1}{15} & -\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and its inverse
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1225}{1024} & \frac{525}{1024} & \frac{315}{1024} & \frac{175}{1024} \\
 \frac{525}{1024} & \frac{1425}{1024} & \frac{615}{1024} & \frac{315}{1024} \\
 \frac{315}{1024} & \frac{615}{1024} & \frac{1425}{1024} & \frac{525}{1024} \\
 \frac{175}{1024} & \frac{315}{1024} & \frac{525}{1024} & \frac{1225}{1024} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
When you multiply $Q^{-1}$ by a vector of $1$s (equal to taking its row sums) you get an elliptical shape, as expected from lifting line theory.

It is positive definite, an *M-Matrix* so its inverse has all positive elements (a positive matrix), and a few other interesting characteristics.

An expression for its inverse is known (messy combinatorial one) and I've proven the summation property for the inverse (using automated theorem proving I learned about from here). A 1958 paper gave the expression for a matrix scaled by a factor of 2 from $Q$, but did not note the sum of elements.

For $n$ odd, it appears that none of the partial sums of elements of $Q^{-1}$ are integers, just the total sum. This appears true for $n$ even too, except for obvious cases for half of the elements.

I've since added it to the Integer Sequence Library. https://oeis.org/A000217

Curious to toss this out there and see if anyone else finds it intriguing.

EDIT:
It is also the sum $H$ and $H^T$, $Q=H+H^T$, where $H$ has elements of 
$$
h_{i,j}=\frac{1}{2 (i-j)+1}
$$
So $H$ is a generalized Hilbert Matrix. $H$ has the property that for an $n$-dimensional matrix, the elements of $H^{-1}$ sum to $n$.

Comment: This makes me think of a Hilbert matrix.

Comment: There's a generalized Hilbert matrix lurking in there. Updated post to reflect.